# WPF double-binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

**Problem**
I am creating a bunch of ellipses and I want their fill-brush opacity to change according to a slider value. I bind the slider to a property and bind the ellipse's FillProperty to the same property through a converter. When I update the slider, the ellipses don't change. They do change when I recreate them, however.

I intuit that the Ellipse binding doesn't see the change that I am making through the other binding, and therefore doesn't update. I don't know what flag to set to cause it to cascade the changes that I am making to the property, or if I need to wrap the property in some kind of a fancy object.

Would appreciate any help.

**Technical Details**
I have a class ( :Window) that declares a (public, auto) property called `BubbleOpacity`. At some point I create a slider and bind it (Two-way) to my property.

```
var slider = new Slider { Width = 150, Minimum = 0, Maximum = 1, Value = 0.2 };
slider.SetBinding(RangeBase.ValueProperty, new Binding("BubbleOpacity") { Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
```

So far so good. Then I create a few ellipses. One of these ellipses may look like so:

var ellipse = new Ellipse {
            /* I set Width, Height, Margin, Stroke...  etc. 
            };
ellipse.SetBinding(Shape.FillProperty, new Binding("BubbleOpacity") { Source = this, Converter = new BrushOpacityConverter(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGoldenrodYellow)) });

The `BrushOpacityConverter` class just creates a new brush, based on the passed opacity value. It looks like this, if you must know.

```
class BrushOpacityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private readonly Brush _brush;

    public BrushOpacityConverter(Brush brush)
    {
        _brush = brush;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var brushclone = _brush.CloneCurrentValue();
        brushclone.Opacity = (double) value;
        return brushclone;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

If I set breakpoints on the Convert method, I see that it doesn't get called when I update my slider. It does get called (correctly) when I recreate the ellipses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you change the `BubbleOpacity` property you don't notify anybody that you have changed it.

To fix this you can implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the PropertyChanged event when the BubbleOpacity property changes.

Another option is to declare the `BubbleOpacity` property as a dependency property, like this:

```
public double BubbleOpacity {
   get { return (double)GetValue(BubbleOpacityProperty); }
   set { SetValue(BubbleOpacityProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty BubbleOpacityProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("BubbleOpacity", typeof(double), typeof(Window), new UIPropertyMetadata(1d));
```

I would prefer the second option (because this property is declared inside a DependencyObject).

Comment: Thank you very much, works as advertised. It would have taken eons to find this with google, so again, thanks for typing up a solution. =)